# String to binary and back using pure SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I know how to convert string to its binary representation.

```
WITH string(s) AS (VALUES('string')),
     bytes(i, j, b, s) AS (
        VALUES(1, 0, '', (SELECT s FROM string))
        UNION ALL
        SELECT i + 1, j + 1, UNICODE(SUBSTR(s, i, 1)), s FROM bytes
        LIMIT (SELECT LENGTH(s) + 1 FROM string)
     ),
     octets(i, o) AS (
        VALUES(1, '')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT i + 1, '' FROM octets
        LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(b) FROM bytes WHERE b <> '')
     )
SELECT replace(group_concat((
   WITH bin(n, c) AS (
      VALUES(7, '')
      UNION ALL
      SELECT n - 1, CASE (b >> n) & 1
                       WHEN 1 THEN '1'
                       ELSE '0'
                    END FROM bin
      LIMIT 9
   ) SELECT replace(group_concat(c), ',', '') FROM bin
)), ',', '')
FROM bytes b
JOIN octets o
ON b.j = o.i;
```

The result is `"011100110111010001110010011010010110111001100111"`. Is it possible to convert them back into regular view with pure SQLite? Does this require temporary tables or it can be solved with nested `WITH RECURSIVE` constrictions?

Comment: Which string do these bits represent?

Comment: From example above `"011100110111010001110010011010010110111001100111"` equals `"string"`

Comment: Can you please explain why? What encoding is used? There are 42 bits. How do they represent `string`?

Comment: I fixed misspeling, there are 48 bits.

Comment: OK, so now the bits represent `string` in ASCII. How saved the like this? Why? Using what programming language or `INSERT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found more pretty way to do [this](https://github.com/gregzakh/notes/tree/master/sqlite#converting-to-binary). Converting string to binary representation:

```
WITH bits(i, s) AS (
   VALUES(1, '') UNION ALL
   SELECT i + 1, (
      WITH bin(p, b) AS (
         VALUES(7, '') UNION ALL
         SELECT p - 1, (UNICODE(
            SUBSTR('this is test string', i, 1)
         ) >> p) & 1 FROM bin LIMIT 9
      ) SELECT group_concat(b, '') FROM bin
   ) AS c FROM bits WHERE c <> ''
) SELECT group_concat(s, '') FROM bits;
```

And back:

```
WITH octets(c, s) AS (
   VALUES('', '0111010001101000011010010111001100100000011010' ||
       '01011100110010000001110100011001010111001101110100001' ||
       '00000011100110111010001110010011010010110111001100111')
   UNION ALL
   SELECT SUBSTR(s, 1, 8), SUBSTR(s, 9) FROM octets WHERE s <> ''
) SELECT group_concat(CHAR(
   SUBSTR(c, 1, 1) * 128 + SUBSTR(c, 2, 1) * 64 +
   SUBSTR(c, 3, 1) * 32  + SUBSTR(c, 4, 1) * 16 +
   SUBSTR(c, 5, 1) * 8   + SUBSTR(c, 6, 1) * 4  +
   SUBSTR(c, 7, 1) * 2   + SUBSTR(c, 8, 1)
), '') FROM octets WHERE c <> '';
```

Answer (score 3):

You should create function or do it at application level, but let's give a try with pure SQL:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cnt(x) AS (
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT x+1 FROM cnt
     LIMIT 100
), bin(b) AS(
   VALUES ('011100110111010001110010011010010110111001100111')
  )
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CHAR(
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(b, 1+(c.x-1)*8, 8), 1, 1) * 128 +
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(b, 1+(c.x-1)*8, 8), 2, 1) * 64 +
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(b, 1+(c.x-1)*8, 8), 3, 1) * 32 +
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(b, 1+(c.x-1)*8, 8), 4, 1) * 16 +
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(b, 1+(c.x-1)*8, 8), 5, 1) * 8 +
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(b, 1+(c.x-1)*8, 8), 6, 1) * 4 +
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(b, 1+(c.x-1)*8, 8), 7, 1) * 2 +
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(b, 1+(c.x-1)*8, 8), 8, 1) * 1 
    ), '') AS result
FROM bin b
JOIN cnt c
  ON c.x <= LENGTH(b)/8;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=d65519d81272ec39372b4c8fd3d723af)**

How it works:

- cnt(x) tally/number table
- bin(b) our binary representation
- main query

  - split 48characters into 8 chunks
  - convert to number
  - CHAR -> get string representation
  - group_concat - get one string

Of course there is a place for a lot of improvements.

Comment: Nice decision. How to avoid multiple typing of `"SUBSTR"`? I suppose that it better to split binary string to octets, after that convert them in to numbers. Something like this (pseudo)`WITH conv(i, p, c, d) AS (VALUES(1, 128, '') UNION ALL SELECT i + 1, p / 2, SUBSTR(octet, i, 1) * p, d + p FROM conv LIMIT 8) SELECT CHAR(d) FROM conv;`

Comment: @KatePage Internal `SUBSTR` in my example could be easily avoided by wrapping with subquery. SUBSTR to get each digit of byte also could be changed (maybe some printf() trick to convert `01010110` -> INT

Comment: As I know `printf()` can not convert bin to integer.